# Python - replace exec for dynamic variable creation

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have been told that using exec is a Very Bad Thing.

However, I'm new to python and trying to figure out how to dynamically create a bunch of global variables (I'm aware that this is also supposed to be a Bad Thing, but let's burn one bridge at a time, shall we?).

What this is doing: get a list of the current variables that need to be created (currently sitting in a CSV), get the unique ID's within that list, then create the necessary objects by appending the ID to the name and reading the content of another CSV into it.

```
import pandas as pd

def importtest():
    ilist = pd.read_csv('Z:/fakepath/ID.csv')
    for i in range(0, len(ilist['ID'].unique())):
        tempID = ilist['ID'].unique()[i]
        exec("variable%s = pd.read_csv('%s')" % (
            str(tempID), 'Z:/fakepath/'+str(tempID)+'.csv'), globals())
        i = i + 1
```

Is there another/better way to dynamically create/update the variables I need so they show up in the global scope?

Comment: As you seem to be aware, this is not a good idea.  Why do you want to do this?  Just make a global dictionary called `variable`, and then do `variable[tempID] = whatever`.  What problem do you have that that does not solve?

Comment: Looks like that solves both of my problems, actually. Thanks!

Comment: @BrenBarn, might as well write it up as an answer so the original poster can mark it correct.  A couple minor comments -- I don't think you need the `i = i + 1` line, since your `i` is looping already anyway.  Also, I think it would be cleaner to write `for temp_id in ilist['ID'].unique():` instead of creating an index.  The id values are all you actually care about, so just loop over those.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

String keys in `globals()` dictionary correspond to variable names, so, you don't need to use `exec`, you can write variable to globals hash directly:

```
     globals()["variable" + str(tempID)] = pd.read_csv('Z:/fakepath/'+str(tempID)+'.csv')
```

Comment: Accepting this answer, because while BrenBarn's comment solved my problem, I feel that this answer is actually a closer solution to my question as asked.